# MySQL (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")") on Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi guys i try to update an old project from 4 years ago, the project was made in **laravel 5.1**, so I think I put almost all good, but when I run php artisan migrate I got this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `recetas_db`.`orders_items` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `orders_items` add constraint `orders_items_course_id_foreign` foreign key (`course_id`) references 
>   `courses` (`id`) on delete cascade)

this is the code of each table

```
Schema::create('orders_items', function (Blueprint $table) {


$table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('utensil_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('qty');
    $table->integer('type')->default(1);
    $table->float('price');
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('order_id')
        ->references('id')->on('orders')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('utensil_id')
        ->references('id')->on('utensils')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('course_id')
        ->references('id')->on('courses')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});


 Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('video')->nullable();
            $table->string('video_preview')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('short_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->string('time')->nullable();
            $table->integer('teacher_id');
            $table->float('score');
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

I saw other similar posts but i can get the right answer for me and I can't see where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

It is the `orders_items` table table of `integer` not being a `bigInteger`

You can try can change

```
Schema::create('orders_items', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

to

```
Schema::create('orders_items', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id')->nullable();
```

And make sure Courses table migration happens before the Order Items migration.

It may also be because you are using soft deletes on the courses table but no the the order_items table.

Try adding `$table->softDeletes();` to the `orders_items` migration and make sure you update the order item model to handle sofdeletes and use the sofdeletes trait.